# Disable Caching of a Swf File

Tags: c#

Is it possible to disable the caching of a swf file loaded trough an axShockwaveFlash object in a Windows Form Application?

Having to use a WindowsBrowser object to obtain that result sounds like an overkill.

PS: yes, I've already tried disabling the caching as a whole in internet explorer ( forcing the browser to load a page everytime it opens it), but somehow flash seems to ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

outside flash

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)  
{  
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));  

    context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();  

    FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead("path_to_swf_file");  
    byte[] BannerData = new byte[fs.Length];  
    fs.Read(BannerData, 0, BannerData.Length);  

    context.HttpContext.Response.ExpiresAbsolute = dt;  
    context.HttpContext.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";  
    context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");  
    context.HttpContext.Response.Charset = "utf-8";  
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;  
    context.HttpContext.Response.Expires = -1;  
    context.HttpContext.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";  
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash";  
    context.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=...");  
    context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(BannerData);  

    fs.Close();  

    context.HttpContext.Response.End();  
}
```

inside

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(whatever url);
request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache"));
request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Expires", "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, -1"));
request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"));
loader.load(request);
```

Comment: I'm developing a c# application, I'm not sure what php has to do with it

Comment: The first piece of code is C#/ASP.Net, the second part is Actionscript/Flash so there is no php code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can always append a current timestamp in milliseconds to the url of the SWF file.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work : the file is still cached and every execution after the first one, is taken from the stored file

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're specifying a HTTP URI in your axShockwave control.

The Shockwave Flash player can play an SWF file before it has downloaded completely, the easiest way to do that is to specify the network address in the control, but as you say, you're running into cache invalidation issues.

If the SWF file isn't too big (i.e. downloads completely in under a few seconds) then I'd download it using HttpWebRequest or WebClient, save it to a temporary file on disk, then load it in the player by the local path. Note that this will break the SWF if it depends on any domain security options (Flash player restricts certain actions unless the SWF originates from the same domain as the requested action, which obviously breaks if the SWF is running locally as there is no domain).

The only alternative I can think of (as I haven't used the Flash ActiveX control myself since 2003, yep, 9 years ago) is to remove, dispose, then recreate the control - but I don't know if there's any persistent caching going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I can't download it, because it's a flash application that makes an heavy use of sockets, and I can't break them. And, since I need to run multiple instances of the flash file, I can't either dispose of it